# Writing a script that would run in browser or NodeJS

Tags: node.js, browser

I wrote this little example:

```js
import { isBrowser, isNode } from "browser-or-node";

// runs at load
async function run() {
  if (isBrowser) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    
  } else if (isNode) {
    const fs = await import("./myLittleScript");
    console.log(fs);
  }
}

run()
```

And `./myLittleScript` is actually importing the node filesystem module to use if the user runs the script in node.

Is this idea wrong ? What is the right approach ?

I get an error that the script is not found, even though it is in the same directory than the `index.ts` which is the code pasted here.

This is when bundling it with webpack, but I am interested in knowing whether this is an acceptable approach or not. (I know I could just write 2 functions.)

Comment: Add the file extension, `const fs = await import("./myLittleScript.js");`.

Comment: But shouldn't TS just find the file @jfriend00 ? (which is a `./myLittleScript.ts`)

Comment: I see, yes I was aware. And does it make sense to webpack `node:fs`  ? I am confused with that. Yes, you are right in the second bit, I was just obfuscating it I think.

Comment: I would assume webpack, when building for nodejs will understand what `node:fs` is (a built-in module).

Comment: But this is bundling (which I mean resolving all the imports to a single output file) for the web or for node. Basically I want a single script that runs in both, using the right code for each case.

Comment: I'm not a webpack expert, but I thought the point of webpack was to bundle for a particular target and not use the exact same bundle in both places.  You can use the same source, but bundle separately for each so you're including just the relevant code for each platform in the bundle.

Comment: Thanks, I'm so confused though. Say I bundle for two targets (node and web), what would webpack do with the filesystem module in that script ?

Comment: `node:fs` is built into the nodejs runtime.  Webpack knows that and never puts it in the bundle even when building a target to run in nodejs.  `node:fs` can't be used in a browser because it doesn't exist there and can't run there (the underlying functionality it uses does not exist in a browser).  Code that will run in both places has to be based on common libraries that can run in both places.

Comment: Thank you. Took me a while and partially is a problem in webpack, but you were correct @jfriend00